# Django how to detect if a form field was filled in?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

In my `models.py`, I override `save()` to manipulate the ImageField before saving it.

```
class Image(models.Model):
    caption = models.Charfield(max_length=254)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.image:
            # image manipulations
            super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The manipulation should not run on the image if the object is saved without changing the ImageField, i.e. the user changes some other field like a CharField and updates the object. I didn't test this, but I presume that in the above code, self.image will always be True even if the user saves without uploading a new image to replace the old one.

So, I plan to check this based on whether or not an image file was uploaded by the user to begin with:

```
if form.is_valid():
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    if form.cleaned_data.get('image'):
        image_was_uploaded = True
    instance.save(image_was_uploaded=image_was_uploaded)
```

Is this a valid method to accomplish this, or is there a better/more Pythonic approach (that hopefully works within `models.py` so Admin and DRF benefit from the same functionality)?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at a custom ImageField, which would handle your custom processing in its clean method. Take a look at this for instance: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2206/

Comment: How would I know if a new file was uploaded to replace the old one?

Comment: Try looking at the type of file you get and if it is an instance of UploadedFile: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/files/uploads/#uploaded-files

Comment: This looks like it'd be the most natural way to do it. I don't know how to access/use this though, is it correct to say `type(request.FILES['image']) == django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile` or is it better as `isinstance(request.FILES['image'], django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile)`?

Comment: Use the isinstance() function, it is more pythonic and handles potential subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in the form class itself by overriding the clean method and checking it. 
when you call is_valid() from your view then it will inturn call the clean method where you can do this checking.